# How to Expand inbetween Numbers in VBA

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba, macros, automation

I need to expand Some numbers from one to another

Like when input is 399207 and 10 = Output  399207 399208 399209 399210

Input:

```
422209           10
904L1009         10
356608           11
0003ML00030-1    3
00EO0632         33
00SH0062         65
0177-5002        3
01RLCB0082901001 3
02AE0078         81
02ID0081         82
0301ME001218-1   3
07HY0569         71
327798           800
336999           7000
```

Currently i use User defined sub function for this process

This is my code

```
Function EXPAND_serial(pno As String, n As String, _
                       Optional delim As String = "@")

    Dim m As String, i As Long, pnos As Variant

    m = Right(pno, Len(n))
    pno = Left(pno, Len(pno) - Len(n))
    ReDim pnos((m) To (n))

    For i = (m) To (n)
        pnos(i) = pno & (i)
    Next i


    EXPAND_serial = Join(pnos, delim)

End Function
```

When i use this code its working fine (01 to 09) for major numbers but If cross 09 to 10 or more

***It skip 0's*** So input digit not match with each output digit length if 0's comes

See my Snap For better understanding. How to fix this help me

Light Red Background highlights have problem

[image]

Comment: I'm sure you will have to modify your concatenation line `pnos(i) = pno & (i)` for when your number is bigger than 10...

Comment: @gns100 but how to join it without & operator

Comment: i think lenth of (m) is  trimmed itself . For calculation 09=9 like this way. how to prevent it without skip 0s

Comment: @jeepad thanks for mention that bug. now i update the input with one formula... Sorry for the inconvenience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems very simple, please correct if I am wrong, by using the function `String(Number, Character)` you can have it done. You can understand more about this function [here](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/functions/string-function.htm).

```
Function EXPAND_serial(pno As String, n As String, _
                       Optional delim As String = "@")

    Dim m As String, i As Long, pnos As String

    m = Right(pno, Len(n))
    pno = Left(pno, Len(pno) - Len(n))
    ReDim pnos(m To n)

    For i = m To n
        pnos(i) = pno & String(Len(n) - Len(CStr(i)), "0") & i
    Next i

    EXPAND_serial = Join(pnos, delim)

End Function
```

P.S.: I have removed extra parenthesis to make code more readable.

Comment: You are excellent Sir... Its working perfectly.... Thank you very much. After Update
`pnos As String > pnos As Variant` this its perfect

Comment: Not a problem .